# Difficulties while trying to style individual list-view cells, like a chat app

Tags: java, css, listview, javafx, listcellrenderer

For my Chat GUI, I'm trying to 'show' the messages styled as Facebook's Messenger does, or at least, in that manner. If I'm the one sending them, they should be aligned to the right, if I'm getting a message from anyone else, they should be aligned to the left, and their background-color should be different.

I've made something similar, but it really looks ugly, and on top of this, I cannot style them individually, but in the even-odd way, so it looks something like this, even tho, a message has never been sent to 'create' them.[image]

The message structure is really simple

```
public void sendMessageOnClick(){
        sendButton.setOnAction((e) -> {
            String message = textInput.getText();
            chatHistory.getItems().add("Sorin: " + message + "\n");
            textInput.clear();
            sendButton.setDisable(true);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the code you've posted is related to styling the messages... But Have you tried modifying the javafx layout file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use a cell factory returing custom `ListCell`s:

```
@FXML
private ListView<ChatMessage> chatHistory;

private String user = "Sorin";
private static final PseudoClass USER_MESSAGE = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("user-message");

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    sendButton.disableProperty().bind(textInput.textProperty().isEmpty());

    final ColumnConstraints ownUserConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
    ownUserConstraints.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);
    ownUserConstraints.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

    final ColumnConstraints foreignUserConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
    foreignUserConstraints.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
    foreignUserConstraints.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

    final ColumnConstraints userConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
    userConstraints.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);

    chatHistory.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<ChatMessage>() {

        private final Label message;
        private final Label userName;
        private final GridPane content;

        {
            message = new Label();
            userName = new Label();
            content = new GridPane();
            content.setHgap(10);
            content.addRow(0, userName, message);
            content.getColumnConstraints().addAll(userConstraints, userConstraints);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(ChatMessage item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            boolean userMessage;
            if (empty || item == null) {
                userMessage = false;
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                userMessage = user.equals(item.getUserName());
                userName.setText(item.getUserName() + ":");
                message.setText(item.getMessage());
                setGraphic(content);

                content.getColumnConstraints().set(1, userMessage
                        ? ownUserConstraints
                        : foreignUserConstraints);
            }
            pseudoClassStateChanged(USER_MESSAGE, userMessage);
        }

    });
}
```

```
public class ChatMessage {

    private final String userName;
    private final String message;

    public ChatMessage(String userName, String message) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

}
```

```
sendButton.setOnAction((e) -> {
    ...
    chatHistory.getItems().add(new ChatMessage(user, message);
    ...
});
```

#### CSS Stylesheet:

```css
.list-cell {
    -fx-background: lightblue;
}

.list-cell:user-message,
.list-cell:empty {
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background;
}

.list-view:focused .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar;
}
```

---

BTW: For a alignment of the own user's message that does not overlap other usernames you need to set the with of `userConstraints` to the largest text width for the user names...

Comment: Looks like what I needed! But what if I want to have different ListView for every chat available?

What I mean by that, is, when I click a button, it should switch to a different ChatHistory (ChatList)

Comment: `listView.setItems(newChatHistory)`?

Comment: Why not? Replaces the items which updates the `ListCell`s If you need to change the "active user" you can also wrap the user name in a property and update the cells from a listener when it changes... If you're asking about creating multiple scenes though: there's nothing that prevents you from loading the fxml multiple times.

Comment: I just need to switch the current chat conversation. I've tried what you said, but somehow, the closest I got, was switching it, but not being able to switch back. What I mean by that, when I wanted to switch to the first one, it would be empty (not stored I guess?).